# With iOS push certificates, why does having an SSL certificate allow Apple to know that its your server they're connecting with?

Tags: ios, ssl, push-notification, ssl-certificate

I'm reading [this article](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-an-ios-push-certificate) on iOS push certificates, and I'm confused about this paragraph:

`Your backend sends notifications through Apple's servers to your application. To ensure that unwanted parties are not sending notifications to your application, Apple needs to know that only your servers can connect with theirs. Apple therefore requires you to create an SSL certificate to be able to send push notifications.`

My understanding of SSL certificates is that if a server has one, that server is able to encrypt data that it sends to a device. But it says here `Apple needs to know that only your servers can connect with theirs`. I don't understand how having an SSL certificate ensures that. Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article shouldn't have used the term *SSL Certificate*. SSL is the *Secure Sockets Layer* (which was superseded by TLS many years ago). SSL and TLS define the handshake that is used to negotiate encryption on a connection.

Enabling SSL on a web server required you to have a certificate to verify your server's identity and so this became known colloquially as an "SSL certificate".

While it isn't often used on the web, in SSL/TLS both parties can present a certificate so that there is mutual authentication.

What you typically have is actually an [x.509 certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509).  This is the case with the push notification service.

An x.509 certificate contains some information including the identity of the certificate holder, their private key and a signature from a trusted party that can be used to verify the information.

For push notifications, the developer generates a certificate request and submits this to Apple who *sign it* with their private key. Apple is the trusted party in this case.

When this certificate is subsequently presented to Apple's server they can verify that signature using their public key to confirm the identity of the connecting party.

You have has encrypted the message with their private key (Apple can decrypt it with the public key included in the certificate).

What this means is, that as long as the developer has kept their private key secure (which is why you wouldn't connect directly to the push service from your app, for example) then Apple can be sure of the identity of the server making the connection.

If someone was trying to impersonate your server then, as long as you have kept your private key secure, they can't encrypt the data properly. If they use a forged certificate that uses a public/private key pair known to them then the signature on the certificate won't be valid and Apple will reject it.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation. I have a few clarifying questions. First, where you say "their private key and a signature". With public key encryption, wouldn't it be the server's public key, rather than their private key, that they share with Apple?

Comment: There was a typo (can instead of can't). Yes, your public key is one of the things Apple signs with their private key when they issue your certificate.  You need to use the private key to sign the information you send to Apple's server when you want to authenticate to send a push.  Apple uses your public key to confirm the signed information is correct (and can only have been signed by you since only you have the private key).   The public key they get from the x.509 certificate you present, which they signed with their private key, so they know they can trust it and the public key in it.

Comment: Ok thanks. So big picture, in this whole transaction, what is the server communicating with Apple, and where does OneSignal fit in? Is the server just the server associated with whatever third-party app is sending the push notification to the other app? If so, then I understand that this third-party app server sends its push notification to another app via Apple's servers, but then where does OneSignal sit in that chain of events?

Comment: I've approved your answer btw. I also asked another question here if you have any insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61209927/onesignal-where-should-i-use-onesignal-account-credentials-vs-my-own-credential